# What type of weather chart is this?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, weather

I like the look of this chart for weather data but I do not know the name of the chart type.

I may try to render my own version but I would like to know if any chart libraries (Javscript Based) support it but I need to know its name.

Maybe someone has written it for D3.js ?

[image]

Comment: What kind of flower is this? http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/flowers/flowers-02.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Its Called a climogram

https://www.climate.gov/maps-data/dataset/average-hourly-climate-conditions-climograms

http://janmilosh.com/d3-weather-graph.html - this should be at least a good starting point

Comment: Thanks for that - all I needed to know.

Comment: 1up for providing an answer even though the question is in no way a good fit for StackOverflow.